# Append orWhere() to dynamic subquery

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

User can submit a search form with an input such as `dog cat +bird`. This is expected to return all Posts with title containing (`dog` OR `cat`) AND `bird`.

I believe I need to append `dog` and `cat` in a subquery such as :

```php
protected function orLike(string $column, string $value): Builder
{
    return $this->builder
        ->where(function (Builder $subQuery) use ($column, $value) {
            $subQuery->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%'); // dog
            //$subQuery->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%'); // cat
            //$subQuery->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%'); etc...
        });
}
```

above `orLike` is my function in a loop that runs for each parsed optional search term (`dog`, `cat`)

How do I make it so that each optional terms (`dog`or `cat`) APPEND to the `$subquery` with an `orWhere()` for each term?

Right now, obviously, it fires a new `where()` with a single subquery for each term.

Not sure if I am clear enough. Basically I am trying to build a rather simple search input where users can type `+bird -cat dog duck` meaning `bird` MUST be in the title AND `cat` MUST NOT be in the title AND (contains `dog` OR `duck`)

edit: additional info as per request in the comments

```php
/*
usage: return $this->parseLike('title', '+dog cat -bird elephant duck');
*/

protected function parseLike(string $column, string $value)
{

    // [...] irrelevant code

    /*
    $terms is a collection of terms, such as:
    +dog
    cat
    -bird
    elephant
    duck
    */

    return $terms
        ->unique()
        ->map(function (string $term) {
            switch (\substr($term, 0, 1)) {
                case '+':
                    return ['like' => \substr($term, 1)]; // function "like()" is called for terms with operator "+" such as "+dog"
                case '-':
                    return ['notLike' => \substr($term, 1)]; // function "notLike()" is called for terms with operator "-" such as "-bird"
                default:
                    return ['orLike' => $term]; // function "orLike()" is called for terms with no operator, such as "elephant" or "duck" or "cat"
            }
        })
        ->each(function ($combination) use ($column) {
            collect($combination)
                ->reject(function ($term) {
                    return empty($term);
                })
                ->each(function (string $term, string $operator) use ($column) {
                    return $this->{$operator}($column, $term);
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: Could you plz share the code where/how you're calling `orLike(...)` method

Comment: "my function in a loop that runs for each parsed optional search term" I think you would need to pass all terms to the function and loop over them within the closure. Possibly you could use `$subQuery->wheres` to find the subquery and alter it instead, but seems like a potential problem.

Comment: Edited post. I'm not sure altering the ```$subQuery->wheres``` is great, I thought about it at first sight but that seems like a big mess hard to read/maintain in the future. There must be a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: I really suggest you reading about Elasticsearch. This kind of search is really easier and faster to do with it, although it adds another complexity layer to your application (another service, ram usage, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this example, I believe you can integrate it to your code.

All you need is to create arrays with values you 1.need, 2.don't need, 3.may be

```
    $mustBe = ['dog', 'cat'];
    $mustNotBe = ['bird'];
    $mayBe = ['tiger', 'lion'];

    $model = SomeModel::query();

    foreach ($mustBe as $term){
        $model->where('title', 'like', '%'. $term . '%');
    }
    foreach ($mustNotBe as $term){
        $model->where('title', 'not like', '%'. $term . '%');
    }

    if($mayBe){
        $model->where(function ($query) use ($mayBe) {
            foreach ($mayBe as $term){
                $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'. $term . '%');
            }
        });
    }

    $result = $model->get();
    dd($result);

    // this builder will return something like this
    $result = SomeModel::where('title', 'like', '%dog%') // dog must be
        ->where('title', 'like', '%cat%') // cat must be
        ->where('title', 'not like', '%bird%') // bird must not be
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%tiger%') // tiger may be
                  ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%lion%'); // lion may be
        })
    ->get();
```

Comment: This does work and is both readable and flexible. Not what I expected, but as elegant as simple. Thank you for your time.